# Httprequest not receiving response from express router

Tags: node.js, express, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to initiate a XMLHttprequest and hoping to receive response from express routes which are being placed in my app.js file but it is not working. Can anybody help what is going wrong
Below are my code in two diff files

File 1

```
       function signup_data_validation() {
           const data = {
           fname: 'Nasir',
           lname: 'Khatri'
           };

           const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
           const url = '../app.js/customers';
           const string_data = JSON.stringify(data);

           xhr.responseType = 'json';
           xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
           if(xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
           console.log(this.responseType);
           }
           }
           xhr.open('POST', url);
           xhr.send(string_data);
           }

           signup_data_validation();
```

File 2:

```
const express = require('express');
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3');
const db = new sqlite3.Database('./miclothing');
const app = express();
app.use(express.static('public'));   // web resources location

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4001;

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
    next();
});

app.post('/app.js/customers', (req, res, next) => {
    const query = req.query;
    query = JSON.parse(query);
    console.log(query.name);
    console.log()
    res.send("Done");
})

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Sever is listening at ${PORT}`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In **File 1** change `const url = '../app.js/customers'` to the URL of your server.

`const url = 'http://localhost:4001/app.js/customers'`

You may change the port if the server is not listening on 4001

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however it is still not working receiving following error POST http://localhost:4001/customers 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Ah that is because you make the POST request to  `http://localhost:4001/customers` not `http://localhost:4001/app.js/customers`. If you want to POST to that URL change the route in `File 2`  to `/customers` like this  `app.post('/customers', (req, res, next) => {})`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assign to a constant(`query = JSON.parse(query);`), this will throw a type error.
You're checking `req.query` instead of `req.body`.
Also in your ajax request you set the responseType to JSON insted of the content type header as you're sending JSON but not receiving it.